# how to use spark(r) to partition data?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have a cluster with 3 nodes. 
I have a json file, with each line being a json string.
I need to partition the data into X blocks based on an ID field in each line of the json file, so that lines of jsons with the same ID will be calculated in the same node.

How can I do the partition?

I am using SparkR, The structure of the code looks like this:

```
getObj=function(x)
{
  rec1= rjson:::fromJSON(x) ;
  kv=list(rec1$id, rec1) ;
  return(kv)
}

data=  SparkR:::textFile(sc, "Path")          
mapdata= SparkR:::map(data, getObj)                          
mapdataP=SparkR:::partitionBy(mapdata,100)
```

The id ranges from 1 to 100. I aim to partition to 100 parts, so each part will have one ID. However, the code above does not give the expected answer. Some partitions are null. For instance, when I try to get the second partition, using
result=SparkR:::collectPartition(mapdataP, 1L), which return Null.

Are there something missing or wrong here? Many thanks!

Comment: For my education (I am a package dev), why are you using private calls, the ones with :::?

Comment: thanks for the comment, because there are some environment conflict. Is there a better way or more appropriate way to do so? Many thanks

Comment: I reported a similar problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6822 No action taken since. I am afraid that's all I know.

Comment: You shouldn't use internal  RDD API in the first place. It has multiple known bugs and some of these lead to a serious loss of function. Since only a very small part of RDD API is currently used by DataFrame API it is probably better to assume that this code has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. It is not exactly true but will save a lot of pain in a long term.